# What does the ⊖ button do in the Windows 8 Devices list?

Tags: windows-8

There is this button-like thing appearing when I click on a device:

[image]

Yet it's missing a tooltip. It could mean “safely remove this device” but it could also mean “uninstall this device driver” and in that case I wouldn't want to try and click it (why is it even there for things like my hard drive?).

So what exactly does this thing do?

Comment: try it in a VM version ^^

Comment: Asking here is as far as I am willing to spend time on this.

Comment: I ll do it as soon as the slow vm starts...

Comment: This looks like your hard drive. Pressing that button will remove it?

Comment: I don't know and if it does I wouldn't want to find out the hard way.

Comment: What I want to know is how you got that ⊖ character in the title text.   is it a alt code character?

Comment: Moab, find the circled minus (U+2296) in the character map and copy it. I'm not really sure what you are referring to with “alt code characters”. It's all just plain old Unicode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short: YES, it does indeed allow you to *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media.*.

But at least there is popup for confirm in case that was an accidental click

[image]

**Update:**

The temptation was too strong... so i tried to Nuke my VM....
but apparently they had thought that someone would try that ^^ - So no you can't nuke your hard drive :D

[image]

Comment: It likely failed to eject the hard-drive because, not surprisingly, there are open handles to that volume. That’s the same behavior in previous versions of Windows.

Comment: That´s why they refer to it "safely"

Comment: @TheBlastOne, you mean *refer **ed***. I see nothing about safety in Windows 8. `:-|`